# How to combine ARRAY formula and RANK formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to apply an ARRAYFORMULA to column T:T from 'Book Rating'!T2 =IF(A:A<>"",RANK($B2:B, INDIRECT(Jotter!$D$18),1),"-") but it's creating an error.

The purpose of this formula is to rank the entries in reverse order and expand to include any new entries (via a Google Form)

Can anyone advise?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rlK4jVdZemv_j-e2wcV-evBtKoKLRCMhs0Fk4uTWc8Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", RANK($B2:B, INDIRECT(Jotter!$D$18), 1), "-"))
```

[image]